# How can I click pages button continuously by x path?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make code that click button continuously using `for`
There are 3 pages and can only use `xpath`

How can I  fix this error?

code

```
for i in range(1,3):
     driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btfTab"]/ul[2]/li[2]/div/div[5]/section[4]/div[3]/button[+str(i)+]').click()
```

Error

[image: Error]

Comment: Do you have an example of the HTML? The error must be in the xpath expression

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding the variable `str` incorrectly to the xPath expression, i.e. you are missing the quote marks.  Try this:

`for i in range(1,3): driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btfTab"]/ul[2]/li[2]/div/div[5]/section[4]/div[3]/button[' +str(i)+ ']').click()`